# Trailing slash gets appended to url in express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, express

I am facing an issue with express server when I am trying to use a specific url route. If I use the word 'bind' for my url automatically a '/' gets appended to it. But it is not happening with other urls that I tried.

Please see the sample server.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/abcd', function (req, res) {
  res.send('abcd');
});


app.get('/bind', function (req, res) {
  res.send('bind');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Results rendered in browser:

[image]

Any reason for this?. Thanks in advance for any help.

UPDATE : Interestingly,this issue is happening in Google chrome only, not in IE or Firefox. So might be a Chrome specific issue.

Comment: I had this problem because of some bug which I had fixed but it kept recurring because of the browser cache. Try disabling the browser cache before reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling `strict routing`. And check for errors, that should help you.

```
var app = express();

app.enable('strict routing');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But when i tried, i am getting " Cannot get '/bind/' "

Comment: Did you try to hit `localhost:3000/bind` without the trailing slash?

Comment: I guess a `301 redirect` is happening. Check your network tab in the developer console.

Comment: Not working for me. Maybe, it's already deprecated.